# Need to pass value of php in jquery script

Tags: php, ajax

I need to pass the PHP retrieved value from database to Ajax function for further querying in database my code is given below.

The PHP Script:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employee") or die(mysql_error());

while($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){  
echo $res['emp_id'];   
$emp_id=$res['emp_id']
```

and submit button with id `name-submit`

The Javascript

```
$('input#name-submit').on('click',function(){ 
var empid = $('php echo $emp_id; ');
alert(empid);
```

the script is running just below the php script.

Comment: you never opened a PHP tag, so how would your server know it's supposed to do some php'ing? If you look at your source code, you'll notice it's just printing the letters you wrote.

Comment: Where do all of you new guys come here from using mysql_query? I wanna send a message to whoever is teaching you this to update his instructions and teach you to use PDO instead.

Comment: @xception Then send a message to internet. Google `mysql php tutorial` and you'll be surprised.

Comment: I see, so google is the one to blame :P

Comment: done bt the in alret box im having [object object] which means it is in array now how cld i xtract the value from it :X help plz

Answer (score 4):

Exactly as you are doing, but by putting the full opening tag in there. Change the second JS line to:

```
var empid = $('<?php echo $emp_id; ?>');
```

Comment: josh acctually  iwasnt ablt to print the php tag here thats y and thanx thing is done but thats was not the problem the main issue i was facing was using old version of jquery library nyway thanx but got new issue in alret box im having undefined